# Can't get the route to work. Need help

Tags: routing

I've installed Ubuntu 16.04.1-server on a HP server. 
I have iLo access, and can connect via built in terminal. (this is the way i installed the OS).

During the installation, I've assigned the ip 172.16.93.119/24 to the machine. It's connected to a network where the gateway is 172.16.93.1.

When I do ifconfig, and route -n i get:
[image]

The problem is, when i try to ping the gateway, or any other ip in network, i get "Desitnation Host Unreachable":

[image]

I've spent more time then i'd love to admit on this, and i'm stuck.

Comment: Are you sure the IP are pingable (I.E not firewalled). You have to ensure that the switch port you are connected to is correctly configured (for example in the correct vlan). Do you control this switch (and the router)?

Comment: Yes, they are pingable. I can ping them from my laptop, but not from the server. I have no direct control of the switch, but i'm assured by admin that it's working correctly.

Comment: If you unplug the network cable from the server and plug it into your laptop  with an IP in the same network (provide you company policy allow this) does it works?

Comment: Heh can't try that. Servers are remote in a data center. I'm pretty sure the physical part is ok.

Comment: Is the port a GB one? or should it be 10Gb?

Comment: do you see the gateway (or any other IP you fail to ping) in your arp table, with the correct MAC? And do you have tshark/wireshark/tcpdump available to see if there is any traffic on the network (e.g. if you see traffic from another subnet, that gives you an argument to convince the switch admin that the port is in the wrong vlan :))

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host or server configurations are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network, or on [su] for a personal network.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

1. Ping 172.16.93.119 from the server
2. Traceroute from the server and from hosts to see where the issue is
3. Use a different IP, sometimes LL providers use interface Vlans to test p2p connectivity and might leave those IP there by mistake

Comment: I can ping 172.16.93.119 just fine

Comment: Can you ping 172.16.93.255 and see if you get any response from any other host? Did you tried step 2 and 3?

Comment: Traceroute i can't try, as i can't install it (no network connectivity :D ). As for pinging the broadcast, 100% packet loss

Comment: As for the IP, that's the one i was assigned to by the sysadmin, so i'll check with him if i can get a different one

Comment: If you can't ping your gateway or any device in the same lan, what do you expect to see in a traceroute that would be of any help?